# ASP.NET - How to have a placeholder value for a data binded dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, database

I am trying to have a placeholder value inside of a drop down list. The drop down list should be a list of stores like Walmart, Kmart, and so on. However, I want the first value item in the list to say "Select a Store." The problem is that I am getting the list of stores from a database table and binding it to the drop down list. So right now, the drop down list displays: Walmart, Kmart, Hmart. I want it to display: Select a Store, Walmart, Kmart, Hmart.
Note: I am using ASP.NET C#.

HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStore" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="80%"     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStore_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code-behind:

```
public void getStores()
{
    objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    objCommand.CommandText = "dbo.Store_Select";

    DataSet ds;
    ds = conn.GetDataSetUsingCmdObj(objCommand);
    ddlStore.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
    /*No Store to display*/
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataRow current_row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            ddlStore.DataTextField = "Store_Name";
            ddlStore.DataValueField = "Store_ID";
        }
    }
    ddlStore.DataBind();
 }
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the binding the DB data to the control `ddlStore.DataBind();` you can simply insert the `ListItem` using

```
ddlStore.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a store", ""));
```

**Full method:**

```
public void getStores()
{
    objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    objCommand.CommandText = "dbo.Store_Select";

    DataSet ds;
    ds = conn.GetDataSetUsingCmdObj(objCommand);
    ddlStore.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
    /*No Store to display*/
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataRow current_row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            ddlStore.DataTextField = "Store_Name";
            ddlStore.DataValueField = "Store_ID";
        }
    }
    ddlStore.DataBind();
    ddlStore.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a store", ""));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @user3470441 Glad it worked, please don't forget to mark the post as the answer.